# Google Protobuf - Protoc Compiling Proto Files with Imports

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

The gRPC examples show use of one proto file and one output file. However, I was supplied a protofile that imports another, which in turn imports several from another directory.

Is the protoc supposed to produce headers and source files from the imported files? Or do you need to run the compiler on every single individual proto file?

Does anyone have an example cmake, where the proto files import?

I've got something like this in my cmake to compile one proto file:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${chat_proto_srcs}" "${chat_proto_hdrs}" "${chat_grpc_srcs}" "${chat_grpc_hdrs}"
    COMMAND ${PROTOC_COMPILER}
    ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    -I "${chat_proto_path}"
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${GRPC_PLUGIN}"
    "${chat_proto}"
    DEPENDS "${chat_proto}")
```

But it doesn't seem to produce anything for any files that are imported from the file pointed to by `${chat_proto}`

I've also tried:

```
# Generated Proto files
file(GLOB_RECURSE proto_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.proto")
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(proto_srcs proto_hdrs ${proto_files} PLUGIN protoc-gen-grpc=${GRPC_PLUGIN})
add_custom_target(proto_dep DEPENDS ${proto_srcs} ${proto_hdrs})
message(STATUS "Generated source files are ${proto_srcs}")
```

However, I do not see any .grpc.pb.cc files or know how to get the list of them to add to compilation of my library with `add_library`. If I understand the docs correctly, I have to compile the `*.pb.cc` files as well as the `*.grpc.pb.cc` files.

Comment: As far as I understand it, yes, you have to call it for very file. or like a regular compiler, add all files to a single invocation